# How to add additional details to Spring Security userdetails

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to add additional information to userdetails like user's Ip address. Is there any way to achieve this? I tried to create a new CustomSpringUser class but the problem is how can i get this information from Authentication object. Is there any other way to store additional information for authenticated user?

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

My custom user class;

```
public class CustomSpringUser extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {

public String ip;

public CustomSpringUser(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    super(username, password, authorities);
}

public CustomSpringUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, String ip) {
    super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    this.ip= ip;
}

}
```

**Edit:** I found that we can add additional information for Authentication but I couldn't found how to do that.
    http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getDetails()

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    try {

        AppUser appUser = new AppUser();
        appUser.setUsername(userName);

        AppUser domainUser = genericDao.getByTemplate(appUser).get(0);

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
        roles.add(domainUser.getRole().getName());

        return new CustomSpringUser(
                domainUser.getUsername(),
                domainUser.getPassword().toLowerCase(),
                enabled,
                accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired,
                accountNonLocked,
                getGrantedAuthorities(roles),
                ***domainUser.getAccount().getIdentificationId())*** ;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        genericLogger.saveLog(Logger.Status.ERROR, "Couldn't login", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which IP adres do you want to know? The ip-address is stored in the `WebAuthenticationDetails` so you don't need to store that that is already available. You can get that by calling `getDetails()` on the authentication object, the UserDetails are available by calling the `getPrincipal()` method on the `Authentication`. See the [javadocs ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getPrincipal()).

Comment: @M.Deinum Ip address was an example. Actually I want to add some other informations to Authentication. I edited my question. I want to get my custom ip variable's value.

Comment: As I mentioned in my inital comment `getDetails()` is NOT for the UserDetails, for that use `getPrincipal()`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks it works. Write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `UserDetails` from the `Authentication` object/instance use the `getPrincipal()` method. The `getDetails()` method is to be used to get additional information about the user (which in general will be an instance of `WebAuthenticationDetails`).

Links

1. Authentication [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html)
2. Authentication.getDetails() [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getDetails%28%29)
3. Authentication.getPrincipal() [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getPrincipal%28%29)