# Spring custom userDetail set user authority

Tags: spring, security

I am trying to customize and add additional information to my Spring Security Principal.  Been looking through the spring doc and also some examples such as this

[How to add additional details to Spring Security userdetails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785591/how-to-add-additional-details-to-spring-security-userdetails)

This examples explicitly set authentication values to true.  For example

```
 boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
    roles.add(domainUser.getRole().getName());

    return new CustomSpringUser(
            domainUser.getUsername(),
            domainUser.getPassword().toLowerCase(),
            enabled,
            accountNonExpired,
            credentialsNonExpired,
            accountNonLocked,
            getGrantedAuthorities(roles),
            ***domainUser.getAccount().getIdentificationId())*** ;
```

Instead of manually setting accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired...etc to true. Is there a Authority method that could check User.Role and get the value of accountNontExpired..etc?

I found another example where they also manually set Authority.... is this the correct way?

http://javahotpot.blogspot.in/2013/12/spring-security-adding-more-information.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your own user model as an extension of the regular user model (as you did) and you have to retrieve the information you need by yourself.

<del>When using Spring's database authentication, the field `accountNonExpired`, `credentialsNonExpired`, etc. are retrieved from columns of the database.</del>

When using Spring's database authentication, it simply sets `accountNonExpired`, `credentialsNonExpired` and `accountNonLocked` to `true`. The property `enabled` is retrieved from the database.

That concludes to: Yes, you have to set these fields on your own.

---

The method `setAuthority(..)` sets the authority object of the `Authentication` object which is a wrapper around the actual authority (in your case the user). The `Authentication` object can be retrieved from the `SecurityContextHolder` and is used to store the authentication status (e.g. whether the user is authenticated).

Comment: "When using Spring's database authentication, the field accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, etc. are retrieved from columns of the database." <-- are you sure?  This is user schema from spring doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#user-schema  it does not have credentialsNonExpired ..etc as columns

Comment: @EricHuang Oh, you are right. I think I threw this together with the LDAP authentication.

But I looked at the code again and the `JdbcDaoImpl` does no more than setting the three field to `true` (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.java). So it should be fine to do that the same.